# can you please help me out to Find a 2×2 matrix A with the help of following conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm very new to linear algebra so I need small help to solve this, so here is the condition.

Each eigenvalue is a complex number with modulus equal to $1$. The eigenvalues remain complex
for $A^n$ for $0 ≤ n ≤ 49$ and become real for $A^{50}$.

Please help me out on this

Comment: If the modulus is $1$, then the number is of the form $\cos t+i\sin t.$

Comment: By “complex”, do you mean a non-real complex number? Note that every real number is complex.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: I completely forgot that $50$ hence the change:

Your eigenvalues are primitive $100^{th}$ roots of the unity, i.e. $\lambda = e^{\frac{2i\pi k}{100}}$ with $k$ and $100$ coprime.
Your characteristic polynomial $\chi_A$ has either one root so $(X-\lambda)^2$ but this is impossible since it has real coefficients, or two roots so $(X-\lambda)(X-\lambda’)$ but once again it has real coefficients so $\lambda’ = \bar{\lambda} = e^{-\frac{i\pi k}{50}}$.

This gives you a $\mathbb{C}$-diagonalizable matrix, which is $\mathbb{C}$-conjugate to:
$$\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \bar{\lambda} \end{pmatrix}$$

This matrix is conjugate to the real matrix:
$$R_\theta = \begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta  \end{pmatrix}$$
The matrix of rotation $\theta = \theta_k =\frac{\pi k}{50}$, $k \wedge 100 =1 \iff k \wedge 10 = 1$.

So $A$ is $\mathbb{C}$ conjugate to $R_\theta$ so it is $\mathbb{R}$-conjugate to it. Hence all the matric you’re looking for are of the form:
$$P^{-1} R_{\theta_k} P$$
For $P$ invertible and $k$ coprime with $10$.

Comment: Why in the world do you downvote this is ridiculous

Comment: $(e^{i \pi/25})^{25} = -1 \in \mathbb{R}$. You want a primitive 100th root of unity, not a 50th.

You likely got a downvote for answering a low effort question (for what it’s worth, I did not downvote)

Comment: right sorry for the mistake, I see why the downvote now thx, deserved

Comment: I downvoted because you just did this guy's homework for him and many of us take a dim view of cheating.

Comment: Yes yes my bad, I was goo impulsive sorry